# How to output a boolean in T-SQL based on the content of a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I made a view to abstract columns of different tables and pre-filter and pre-sort them. There is one column whose content I don't care about but I need to know whether the content is null or not. So my view should pass an alias as "*true*" in case the value of this specified column **isn't null** and "*false*" in case the value **is null**.

How can I select such a boolean with T-SQL?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You have to use a **CASE** statement for this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN columnName IS NULL THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END FROM tableName;
```

Comment: This results in a varchar(5)-column on the view for me, not a boolean. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @uffjohn there's no such thing as "true" or "false" in Sql. Normally it's either 1 or 0, a "bit" flag. If you're using this in .NET code or something, you could cast this value to a boolean there.

Comment: Or do `CAST(CASE WHEN columnName IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS BIT) FROM tableName`

Comment: This is just flat out wrong.  'true' is not boolean.  Labeling the column as bit is also not a bit.

Answer (score 31):

Or you can do like this:

```
    SELECT RealColumn, CAST(0 AS bit) AS FakeBitColumn FROM tblTable
```

Comment: This is what worked for me, specifically with a `CAST(CASE WHEN <predicate> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BIT)`.

Comment: `CAST(0 AS bit)` is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 20):

If you need a output as boolean

```
CAST(CASE WHEN colName IS NULL THEN 0  ELSE 1   END as BIT) aIsBooked
```

Answer (score 9):

for the column in the view you can use something like

```
CASE WHEN ColumnName is not null THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END
```

or in a statement

```
SELECT 
s.ID,
s.[Name],
CASE WHEN s.AchievedDate is not null THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END [IsAchieved]
FROM Schools s
```

or for further processing afterwards I would personally use

```
SELECT 
s.ID,
s.[Name],
CASE WHEN s.AchievedDate is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [IsAchieved]
FROM Schools s
```

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue where I wanted a view to return a boolean column type based on if an actual column as null or not.  I created a user defined function like so:

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsDatePopulated(@DateColumn as datetime)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ReturnBit bit;

    SELECT @ReturnBit = 
        CASE WHEN @DateColumn IS NULL 
            THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 
        END

    RETURN @ReturnBit
END
```

Then the view that I created returns a bit column, instead of an integer.

```
CREATE VIEW testView
AS
    SELECT dbo.IsDatePopulated(DateDeleted) as [IsDeleted] 
    FROM Company
```

Answer (score 5):

You asked for boolean, which we call bit in t-sql.

Other answers have either given you a varchar 'true' and 'false' or 1 and 0.  'true' and 'false' are obviously varchar, not boolean.  I believe 1 and 0 would be cast as an integer, but it's certainly not a bit.  This may seem nit-picky, but types matter quite often.

To get an actual bit value, you need to cast your output explicitly as a bit like:

```
select case when tableName.columnName IS NULL then cast(0 as bit) else cast(1
as bit) END as ColumnLabel from tableName
```

Comment: Nice,useful and correct: just used for having an autogenerating WPF DataGrid's DataGridCheckBoxColumn populated with correct data.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is slightly simpler then the other solutions:

SELECT Cast(ISNULL([column name], 0) AS BIT) AS IsWhatever

Comment: That does not work on T-SQL on non numeric columns as you get a casting error

Answer (score 1):

Since SQL server 2012 you can use `IIF`

```
IIF(columnName IS NULL, 'false', 'true')
```